# Solr synonymfilterfactory is not using the tokenizer provided

Tags: solr

For the synonymfilterfactory, I am using the following configuration:

```
<filter 
    class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" 
    synonyms="synonyms.txt" 
    ignoreCase="true" 
    expand="true" 
    tokenizer="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"
/>
```

But when I index the content, the tokens are not tokenized using the keywordtokenizerfactory

> position    -1-2-3-4-5
>
> term text-i-am-a-cardiologist-specialist
>     ---------------------heart

The token "heart" gets tokenized in the same position as cardiologist and a separate token called "specialist" is created.

In my synonyms.txt, I have mentioned:

> cardiologist,heart specialist

I do not want the synonym "heart specialist" to be split into two tokens(which is why I have mentioned the keywordtokenizerfactory in the synonyms configuration. Is there a way to preserve the multi-word synoym as a single token?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. In a tokenized field, tossing in a multiword keyword term will be all but un-searchable.  You'll parse queries using a tokenizer, then the query will be looking for two tokens "`heart`" and "`specialist`", while you have "`heart specialist`" in your index, and you'll get no results, for either individual terms, or a quoted phrasequery.  Any matches against that field, would have to be constructed manually, or use a keyword analyzer, and if you use a keyword analyzer, then you will not be able to look for something like: "i am a heart specialist", for similar reasons.

Comment: @femtoRgon: Thanks for the comment. But my requirement is quite unique. I will be storing these words as categories. So, only the word called cardiologist will go into the index and not a sentence. Even then, solr splits the synonyms into heart and specialist individually. I want only full match to happen on the synonyms. Is there a way to do it? Also, during the querying phase, I will be using edismax with phrase query, in which case, there will be a match for "heart specialist" as well, though it will also search for "heart" and "specialist" tokens separately.

Comment: A PhraseQuery for `"heart specialist"` will not find the the single token `heart specialist`.  It will find two separate terms, `heart` and `specialist`, in sequence, but to find it as a single token, you would need to analyze the query as a keyword as well.  I think tokenizing normally and using a simple phrase query is the right implementation.

Comment: Thanks femtoRgon. You are right. But I have a complicated work around for such a match using highlighting because my query will not be a simple "heart specialist", but a "I am a looking for a heart specialist in SFO". But is there a way to not make solr split the synonym into two tokens?